# linear programming with logarithm

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, nonlinear-optimization, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

[image]max log $x_1$ + a log $x_2$

subject to

$2$$x_1$+ $x_2$ $\le 8$

$x_1$+$x_2$ $\le 5$

$x_1 \ge 0$ , $x_2 \ge 0$

i need to solve and show optimal solution  when a =1

but how can i find it?

is it possible to use simplex method?

max log $x_1$ + 1 log $x_2$ + 0S1 +0S2

$2$$x_1$+ $x_2$ + S1= 8

$x_1$+$x_2$ +S2= 5

$x_1 \ge 0$ , $x_2 \ge 0$

i can count all possibility $4C2 = 6$ for $Ax=b$ so that $x=A^{-1}b$

i got that

(3,2,0,0), w=log 3+log2

(5,0,-2,0) , w=log 5-2

(4,0,0,1), w=log 4 + log 1

(0,5,3,0), w=log 5+3

(0,8,0,-3), w= log 8 - 3

(0,0,8,5), w= 8+5 =13

is this right? can i use simplex method ? but what is the coefficient?

Comment: The $\log$ destroys linearity.  You might find it simpler to maximize the product $x_1 x_2$, which is an equivalent objective because $\log$ is an increasing function.

Comment: thankyou but how can i acheive that? @RobPratt

Comment: Draw a graph of the feasible region and consider the level curves of $x_1 x_2$.

Comment: @RobPratt i draw the graph and got (3,2,0,0), w=log 3+log2 , is this optimal?

Comment: No, because the objective is nonlinear, you cannot restrict to the extreme points.  But the optimal solution is on the boundary here.

Comment: @RobPratt the other are (5,0) and (0,4) and (0,0) right? but if i count log x1+logx2 , the biggest one is still (3,2)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The extreme points are $(0,0),(0,5),(3,2),(4,0)$.  But unlike for linear programming, you cannot restrict your search for an optimal solution to these points.  The level curves $x_1 x_2=k$ for the objective are rectangular hyperbolas, and the maximization means you want large $k$ (up and to the right).  An optimal solution will appear on the boundary segments from $(0,5)$ to $(3,2)$ or from $(3,2)$ to $(4,0)$.  On each of these two segments, you can eliminate one of the variables, reducing to a one-variable maximization:

- The segment from $(0,5)$ to $(3,2)$ is $x_1+x_2=5$, where $0 \le x_1
     \le 3$.  So $x_1 x_2 = x_1(5-x_1)$, which is maximized when
  $x_1=5/2$, yielding $(x_1,x_2)=(5/2,5/2)$, with objective value
  $(5/2)^2=25/4$.
- The segment from $(3,2)$ to $(4,0)$ is $2x_1+x_2=8$, where $3 \le
     x_1 \le 4$.  So $x_1 x_2 = x_1(8-2x_1)$, which is maximized when
  $x_1=3$, yielding $(x_1,x_2)=(3,2)$, with objective value $3\cdot
     2=6$.

Because $25/4>6$, we have found that $(x_1,x_2)=(5/2,5/2)$ is optimal.

Here's an animation to show the level curves $x_1 x_2=k$ for various values of $k$:
[image]

---

Here's a short alternative solution.  By the AM-GM inequality:
$$x_1 x_2 \le \left(\frac{x_1+x_2}{2}\right)^2 \le \left(\frac{5}{2}\right)^2 = \frac{25}{4},$$
and this upper bound is attained when $x_1=x_2=5/2$.

Comment: Thankyou so much , but i dont understand how do you got $x1x2=k $? , and optimal solution from (0,5) to (3,2) or from (3,2) to (4,0) ? do i have to draw the log curve?

Comment: Plot $x_1 x_2=1$ and $x_1 x_2=10$ together with the feasible region to get some intuition.

Comment: Thankyou , i add picture, but what do you mean by on each of these two segments, you can eliminate one of the variables, reducing to a one-variable maximization?  and what how to reduce the variables?

Comment: If you add to your plot the graphs of $x_1 x_2=6$, $x_1 x_2 = 25/4$ and $x_1 x_2=7$, it might help you see what's going on.  No point $(x_1,x_2)$ with $x_1 x_2 > 25/4$ intersects the feasible region.

Comment: Thankyou but do you get $x_1 x_2 = x_1(8-2x_1)$ is maximized when $x_1=3$ ? do you differentiated it? and also what is the use of knowing $x_1$ range in  $3 \le x_1 \le 4$?

Comment: Without considering the range on $x_1$, the maximum would occur when $x_1=2$ (via calculus or by considering the vertex of this parabola).  But the line segment bounds $3\le x_1 \le 4$, as in your picture.  To find the maximum of a function on a closed interval, you have to also consider the two endpoints.  In this case, the left endpoint yields the maximum over the interval.

Comment: Thankyou but we can see that $8x_1-2x_1 ^2$ , have 2,3,4 as possible points for maximum value, but when i substituted it to $8x_1-2x_1 ^2$  , i got  8,6,0 , so $x_1=2 $ have objective value 8 which is maximum?

Comment: $x_1=2$ is not in the interval $3\le x_1\le 4$.  The point $(x_1,x_2)=(2,4)$ that yields objective value 8 is not feasible because it violates the constraint $x_1+x_2\le 5$.

Comment: Thankyou but the intuition behind this is we want to find the maximum area of the log function that is inside the two function constraint? and also for AM-GM constraint how do you know that $ \left(\frac{x_1+x_2}{2}\right)^2 \le \left(\frac{5}{2}\right)^2 = \frac{25}{4},$  ? how do you know that $\frac{x_1+x_2 }{2}\le \frac{5}{2}$

Comment: I would like to ask one more thing, if we find maximum for $x_1x_2$, is it the same to find log $x_1 x_2=1$? and the answer should be log $\frac{5}{2} + log \frac{5}{2}$?

Comment: $\log x_1 + \log x_2 = \log(x_1 x_2)$ is maximized when $x_1 x_2$ is maximized.